# jQuery get checkbox value if checked and remove value when unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox

jQuery function to get checkbox value if checked and remove value if unchecked.

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/thehero75/HvKmE/3/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="3" />hiiii

<div id="show"></div>

function displayVals(){
var check = $('#check:checked').val();
    $("#show").html(check);
}
var qqqq = window.setInterval( function(){
        displayVals()
    },
    10
);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need an interval, everytime someone changes the checkbox the `change` event is fired, and inside the event handler you can change the HTML of `#show` based on wether or not the checkbox was checked :

```
$('#check').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
    $('#show').html(val);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmE/4/)

Comment: I want to put the value in var, How can I do that??

Comment: How can this be adapted to use multiple checkboxes to add and remove values from the `#show` div?

Answer (score 7):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HvKmE/5/

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked') === true){
           $('#show').text($(this).attr('value'));
        }else{
             $('#show').text('');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way too:

1. Using the new property method will return true or false.

   `$('#checkboxid').prop('checked');`
2. Using javascript without libs

   `document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked`
3. Using the JQuery's is()

   `$("#checkboxid").is(':checked')`
4. Using attr to get checked

   `$("#checkboxid").attr("checked")`

i prefer second option.